# google captcha with button validate-angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, validation

I am using Google re-captcha code in my requirement. I want to validate with button suppose if I choose correct then only button will validate otherwise it was not validate. I tried but I failed please help me to solve this problem thanks in advance
This was my Google captcha script available in online.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

This was my google captcha script available in online

```
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>


<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" name="myForm">Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" style="border: 1px solid #BBDEFB;"id="Name" ng-model="Name" required>Verification code: <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcePAATAAAAAGPRWgx90814DTjgt5sXnNbV5WaW" required<button class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #005baa; color: #fff;" ng-click="myForm.$valid && submit()">Submit</button></div></form>
```

this was my button click event

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    //alert("hi");submit
    $scope.Name = "";
    var _EeqObj = new Object();
    _EeqObj.Name = $("#Name").val();
    _EeqObj.Meth = "WX";
    var httpreq = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "Home",
        data: _EeqObj
    }).success(function (response) {
        if (response == "success") {
            alert("Thank You");
            $window.location.reload();
        }
        else {
            alert("not inserted");
            window.location.replace("#/");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not enough to check only on js client side.
You need to check on your backend server side too. Client side gets string response from google captcha service. Client sends that string to your server. Your server sends that string with private key to google captcha service and decides depending on answer.

UPDATE:
here is code part to use with asp.net web api

angular controller

```
angular
    .module('yourApp', ['vcRecaptcha'])
    .controller('YourController', YourController);

function YourController($scope, vcRecaptchaService) {

    var recaptcha = {
        key: "your recaptcha public key",
        widgetId: null,
        response: null,
        setWidget: function(widgetId) { recaptcha.widgetId = widgetId; },
        setResponse: function(response) { recaptcha.response = response; },
        cbExpiration: function() { recaptcha.response = null; },
        reset: function () {
            recaptcha.response = null;
            vcRecaptchaService.reload(recaptcha.widgetId);
        }
    };

    $scope.recaptcha = recaptcha;

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.info = undefined;
        recaptcha.reset();
    };


    $scope.sendData = function(form, recaptchaResponse) {
        if (form.$invalid) return;
        $http.post('/api/endpoint', { data: ..., recaptchaResponse: recaptchaResponse})
            .then(...
```

angular view

```
<form name="yourForm" novalidate ng-submit="sendData(yourForm, recaptcha.response)>
...
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptchaResponse" ng-model="recaptcha.response" required/>
    <div class="recaptcha-container">
        <div vc-recaptcha theme="'light'" key="recaptcha.key"
             on-create="recaptcha.setWidgetId(widgetId)"
             on-success="recaptcha.setResponse(response)"
             on-expire="recaptcha.cbExpiration()"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="recaptcha-error-info" ng-show="yourForm.$submitted && (yourForm.recaptchaResponse.$invalid || yourForm.$error.recaptcha.length)">
        Pass the check, please
    </span>
...
```

asp.net web api controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class YourApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("endpoint")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] YourVm model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var remoteIp = Request.GetOwinContext().Request.RemoteIpAddress;
        var recaptchaVerifyResponse = await VerifyAsync(model.RecaptchaResponse, remoteIp);

        if (recaptchaVerifyResponse == null || !recaptchaVerifyResponse.Success) return BadRequest("recaptcha error");

        ...
    }


    // may be exrtracted into service
    private async Task<RecaptchaVerifyResponse> VerifyAsync(string response, string remoteip)
    {
        const string RecaptchaVerifyUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

        string responseString;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"secret", "your recaptcha private key"},
                {"response", response},
                {"remoteip", remoteip},
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var postResponse = await client.PostAsync(RecaptchaVerifyUrl, content);
            responseString = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseString)) return null;

        RecaptchaVerifyResponse result;
        try
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecaptchaVerifyResponse>(responseString);
        }
        catch (JsonException)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class RecaptchaVerifyResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    private bool? _success = null;

    public bool Success
    {
        get { return _success == true; }
    }

    [JsonProperty("error-codes")]
    private string[] _errorCodes = null;

    public string[] ErrorCodes
    {
        get { return _errorCodes ?? new string[0]; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: how to do that please tell me

Comment: what is your server technology?

Comment: asp.net with web api using angularjs. these are used in my requirement

Comment: i tried to validate but i failed. please help me Ali

Answer (score 2):

you can use angular-recaptcha

https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha

Comment: i want button validation also